# List files in a specific folder in a document library

Tags: document-library, powershell, csom

I there anyway to output the files of a specific folder in a document library?

Listing them will be like

```
foreach $file in $folder.files
{
    write-host $file.name
}
```

But how do I tell it to look a specific folder?
In CSOM please
Tried the below answer but it did not work

Comment: Use `http://site/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('folder url') /files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below PowerShell script gets files from the given folder recursively:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Function IterateFolderRecurresive([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder] $fld,     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext] $ctx)
{
Write-Host "Files from " $fld.Name
$files = $fld.Files
$ctx.Load($fld.Files)
$ctx.Load($fld.Folders)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($file in $files)
{

    Write-Host $file.Name
}

foreach($subFolder in $fld.Folders)
{
    IterateFolderRecurresive $subFolder $ctx
}

}

$webUrl = Read-Host "Enter your web Url"
#Start Url from relative to Document Library
$folderRelativeUrl ="Documents/Folder2.0/" 
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString 
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($webUrl) 
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("[UserName]",   $password) 
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials
$web = $ctx.Web 
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$folder = $web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($web.ServerRelativeUrl + $folderRelativeUrl)
$ctx.Load($folder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

IterateFolderRecurresive $folder $ctx
```

Hope it will help to you..